# Почему блокирующий запрос к сокету на winapi такой долгий (6 секунд)?

Tags: winapi

```
while ((recv(Socket, buffer, 2048, 0)) > 0){k++;}
```

вот этот цикл проходит один раз и требует  шесть секунд, при том что обращениее идет к веб серверу на вмваре на локалхосте.

Comment: Может, там данных действительно настолько много, что быстрее чем за шесть секунд их передать технически невозможно? Опишите подробнее задачу, чем этот код занимается?

Comment: ответ триста с чем то байт, хидер плюс девять символов

Comment: Тогда странно. А как вы выяснили, что именно этот запрос такой долгий? И почему вы решили, что именно он, а не, например, сервер в вмваре долго отвечает по какой-нибудь причине?

Comment: судя по ваешарку ответ идет спустя десяток миллисекунд

Comment: Ага, а почему вы решили, что шесть секунд пропадают именно в этом участке кода, а не в коде перед ним или в коде после него?

Comment: '`QTime t; int k = 0; t.start(); while ((recv(Socket, buffer, 2048, 0)) > 0){k++;} qDebug("Time elapsed: %d ms", t.elapsed());` ну и в консоли заминку видно

Comment: интересная особенность, если recv вынести из while то сразу все норм, отклик 5мс, тогда как на самом деле работает recv?